# Javascript error in chat (flood control)

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat

I get an error in the chat when the flood control kicks in:

[image: js chat error]

Browsers: Chrome stable and canary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's not really a JavaScript error; that's just Chrome saying that the AJAX request returned a 409 Conflict. That's the status code for the flood control failure, so this is absolutely correct.

Comment: Maybe I should just stop flooding then ;)

Comment: Why 409 and not 429? Hmm seems like the lack of time machine is responsible. Chat is older than the code...

Comment: @CodeInChaos 429? Isn't that still a draft??