# Random bits of my chat die and come back to life during the day

Tags: bug, status-norepro, chat

> Previous question: [Text on chat buttons is gone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244963/text-on-chat-buttons-is-gone)

That was when my buttons died.

On other days, my text dies.

[image: No text]

And some times it's just italics.

[image: Italics gone]

Now, I like blaming @skiwi for this, and he's often nearby when it happens.

But today, he's not here, and it happened again.

[image: italics died again]

I'm running Windows 8 and using Chrome 40.0.2214.94 m.

Refreshing and such does not fix the issue.

Inspect element -> console -> error log:

```
http://chat.stackexchange.com/chats/8595/messages/new Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 409 (Conflict)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZJdJ.png?s=128&g=1&g&s=16 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Bad Gateway)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/boUZp.jpg?g&s=16 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Bad Gateway)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8P3C.jpg?s=128&g=1&g&s=32 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Bad Gateway)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/boUZp.jpg?g&s=16 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 504 (Gateway Time-out)
http://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/19891816 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 409 (Conflict)
```

What's going on here?

I should note, I can view italics by selecting, then alt-tabbing:

[image: I can read italics]

So it reeks of a client-side issue. What's hiding the text from me?

EDIT:

30 april 2015 it happened again =/

[image: bleh]

Comment: How much memory does your computer have? Have you tried inspecting the affected elements?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg <div class="content"><i>test</i></div> The content is just there. I have 8 GB memory.

Comment: If it is a client-side issue (which it apparently is), then I think this doesn't really belong on MSE. Super User (or similar) might be a better fit?

Comment: I don't see how Super User could help me out here...

Comment: I don't see how Meta Stack Exchange could help you here...

Comment: Other users could say "yep, I have this bug too"

Comment: For me closing the browser and opening it again always helped. Good to know I'm not the only one though!

Comment: The 409's you see are from the chatserver if it is [flooded with requests](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124688/158100).   Are you on a corperate network that blocks imgur.com?

Comment: @Pimgd did you by any chance add special options e.g. those suggested in [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/803650/90117)?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I only disabled directwrite, as per the second answer, because it made some website harder to read for me.

Comment: Well, [happened to me just now](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JGCDq.png) - after Chrome restart, all good again. :)

Answer (score 3):

This is a specific issue with either your network provider or something upstream of your connection.  We have no control over these things and are unable to reproduce this issue.

Comment: Not 100% specific, as it happens to me too, once in a while. Still no idea how exactly and how to reproduce, but it looks like some weird Chrome issue

Comment: @ShadowWizard it's most definitely a chrome issue because it happens both at work and at home, from time to time